# How to make API call expired/unique and return data once?

Tags: javascript, node.js, security

I have video site with nodejs as backend. Video is public for everyone so API is also public. This is the problem, they can view API and change params to get more data. I want to protect it from data leaking, spam or crawl.

I want to make each API is unique, each time user send a request, API will return data once. If he visit this API URL again, no data returned. If he refresh page, new API URL is being generated and give him data once. It look like this site https://www.douyin.com/video/7000302017407110436

Data return once only, if you visit below API call URL, it return null like this https://shorturl.at/cwI37

Data showing once like this
[image]

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you right, you would like to send a link to a specific user and this link should only be called once. Here a basic **concept**:

- you create a function that creates a **unique ID** and then you store the unique ID together with the location of the resource. This resource then should not be reachable from outside (not in a public directory)
- you create a **route** like `FQDN/get/:id` where "id" is the unique ID.
- when handling the request, you **search in your storage/DB** if you find the unique ID, then you know, where the resource is located. You now need to do two things:
- **invalidate** the unique ID (removing it from the storage/DB) and
- **serving** the resource from its non pblic location.
- if the unique ID is no longer in your storage (DB), you **just return null**

One problem you might need to tackle: e.g. if you type in a certain url in a the browser, it makes a prefetch while you type it. Which means, that there are situations where a link then is called more then one time.

Comment: Thank you, this look complicated. I want to protect API but this seems not a good choice. Do you have any suggest? I use CORS, but user can access the data from API easy, just change the query.

Comment: CORS is not really a way to protect your API. The concept suggested was just based on your request how to create links that can be used only once. 

To generally protect your API, you can use login/auth mechanism, tokens or any other type of information that JUST the user who needs to access your API knows (and which is specific enough that brute force does not work). Maybe you explain more detailed, what your scenario is ...